# How to make sure that the database file is created only one time?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I just started building a windows forms application. Upon login, the following code is executed. But the problem is that, everytime the user logs in the table is overidden. How can do it so that the database table is created only one time?

```
   SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn;
   SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;
   SQLiteDataReader sqlite_datareader;

   // create a new database connection:
   sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=database.db;Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;");

   sqlite_conn.Open(); 

   sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand(); 

   sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE test (id integer primary key, text varchar(100));";

   sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Why is the application creating a table in the first place?  Shouldn't the database schema already be set up and the application just uses it?

Comment: I apologize. I just started developing desktop application. I was not sure if I could push an existing database file as part of the installation file.

Comment: @prestin - You can install an existing database on the user's machine if you prefer, you don't have to create it in code.

Comment: @keyboardP Thanks for the reply. Which is the preferred way? Adding an existing db file or creating it in code? Also, is there documentation on installing existing db file to the users machine?

Comment: @prestin - It depends on the application but in most scenarios I'd expect to use an existing database schema. How you install it depends on what installer you're using. But installing it would be no different to installing any other file so there's nothing special about the database file itself, you just need to know where it's been installed so that your program can access it.

Comment: @prestin Although you should consider the suggestions below. If you still want to persist edit your code as mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 1):

you need to alter your code like this

```
  sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "create table if not exists test (id integer primary key, text varchar(100));";
```

This will create the table only if it doesn't already exists.

Answer (score 0):

check first if table is exists 
if the table not exists then create table

```
IF OBJECT_ID('test', 'U') IS NULL 
BEGIN 
   CREATE TABLE test (id integer primary key, text varchar(100));
END
```

**For SQL lite**

```
create table if not exists test (id integer primary key, text varchar(100))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on wrong way. I don't really understand your design, but here is a walkthrough, how to create a winform app, which uses SqlLite: [C# Tutorial 36: How to use and connect Sqlite in a C# project](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GLCtoHagrtE)

Try to modify your approach. Don't create table everytime in your code, as David mentioned.